# 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage' error

Tags: asp.net

```
 <%@ Page Title Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/EducationStudio.Master" 

  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.WebForm3"        %>                                                                                                            
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage` instead of `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`.

[See this link](http://www.alphapapahotel.com/system-web-mvc-viewmasterpage-parser-erro/aspnet/)

Comment: instead of System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage try System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Comment: i see ur quetion code WebApplication6.WebForm3 and error page is WebForm4 try to put aspx code for WebForm4 in ur quetion

Comment: have u check my refernced link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12848/discussion-between-nikhil-and-prerna)